# Pop not working properly, stack is always empty

Tags: haskell, stack, push

I've been trying to implement a Stack machine in Haskell for a college work but I'm having a hard time. When I try to push a value into a stack, it always returns only the value I just pushed.

```
module Stack(Stack, push, pop, top, stackEmpty, newStack) where
push :: t -> Stack t -> Stack t
pop :: Stack t -> Stack t
top :: Stack t -> t
stackEmpty :: Stack t -> Bool


newStack   :: Stack t
data Stack t = Stk [t]

newStack = Stk []

push x (Stk xs) = (Stk (x : xs))

                    
pop (Stk [])      = error "retirada em pilha vazia"
pop (Stk (_ : xs)) = Stk xs
top (Stk [])     = error "topo de pilha vazia"
top (Stk (x : _)) = x

stackEmpty (Stk []) = True
stackEmpty _         = False


instance (Show t) => Show (Stack t) where
    show (Stk []) = "#"
    show (Stk (x : xs)) = (show x) ++ "|" ++ (show (Stk xs))
```

This is what happens if I try to push every time in the same stack, it keeps pushing the value to an empty list. I guess that happens because I declared `pilha` as a `newStack` and a `newStack` is an empty list, so every time I push to it it pushes to an empty list, right? The problem is I don't know how to save the value of the stack.

```
ghci> let pilha = newStack 
ghci> push 5 pilha 
5|#
ghci> push 6 pilha
6|#
ghci>
```

This is what I did for it to work in the terminal

```
ghci> let oldStack = push 5 newStack 
ghci> show oldStack
"5|#" 
ghci> let newerStack = push 6 oldStack
ghci> show newerStack
"6|5|#"
ghci> newerStack = push 7 newerStack 
ghci> show newerStack
"
```

I know that that's the logic, every time I push I need to create a new `Stack` that will use the values from the old stack, but I can't seem to figure it out how to code it.

Comment: BTW, that `Show` instance is borderline illegal. `show` should produce valid Haskell code.

Answer (score 4):

If you write `newerStack = push 7 newerStack`, then you define `newerStack` in terms of itself, it thus means that you will `push 7 (push 7 (push 7 (…)))`, and thus end up in an infinite loop.

You thus should implement this as:

```
ghci> let stack1 = push 5 newStack 
ghci> stack1
5|#
ghci> let stack2 = push 6 stack1
ghci> stack2
6|5|#
ghci> let stack3 = push 7 stack2
ghci> stack3
7|6|5|#
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I showed in the last part of my question. My problem is exactly how I am going to create a  function that will do that (create a new stack that will receive the values from an older stack). I've tried many ways but it didn't work, it kept pushing to an empty list. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @DanielGalhardo: you each time take the stack as parameter, and return it as a result (or as a 2-tuple with the first item the stack and the second the result of the computation for example). Or you can work with a `State` monad, which is essentially the same, although with a state monad the syntax thus does not require to explicitly return the stack.

Comment: @DanielGalhardo: see https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad

Comment: Thank you! I'll read it. My teach showed us an example of making a Stack using the State monad because he said that like that we could do something like "main = do  push 3, pop, a <- pop, push 5" so that we could save the value that is being popped and without needing to pass the Stack as a parameter. I'll try to understand it since it seems like it's a better way to implement a stack. Thank you again!

Comment: By default Haskell has no side effects. You are thinking of a stack as an object like in Python,  where you modify it by sending messages to it. Haskell doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 3):

The most direct equivalent to what you tried to do – presumably because you know this style of working from other languages – is to use [`IORef`s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html), which are the only way to have true *mutable variables* in Haskell.

```
*Stack> :m +Data.IORef
*Stack Data.IORef> s <- newIORef (newStack :: Stack Int)
*Stack Data.IORef> modifyIORef s $ push 5
*Stack Data.IORef> readIORef s
5|#
*Stack Data.IORef> modifyIORef s $ push 63
*Stack Data.IORef> readIORef s
63|5|#
*Stack Data.IORef> modifyIORef s pop
*Stack Data.IORef> readIORef s
5|#
```

But there's seldom a good reason to go this route. The reason imperative languages rely so much on mutation is that you use loops as control structures all the time, which requires dealing with variable state while keeping the same variables in use. But in Haskell, you just don't do that – you use recursion instead, and that automatically gives you the opportunity to “modify” values simply by passing different arguments, without needing to invent new variable names.

Even recursion aside – you can just chain multiple updates in a *pipeline*. No variables needed at all:

```
*Stack> pop . push 9 . push 3 $ newStack 
3|#
```

As already mentioned, there's also the [state monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#t:State), which encapsulates pseudo-mutable state. It's mostly useful when you have a whole bunch of different actions that all read and/or mutate the same thing (often this will be some kind of small database or so).

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

statefulExample :: State (Stack Char) ()
statefulExample = do
   modify $ push 'h'
   modify $ push 'e'
   modify $ push 'k'
   modify $ pop
   mapM_ (modify . push) "llo, world"
```

```
*Stack> execState statefulExample newStack 
'd'|'l'|'r'|'o'|'w'|' '|','|'o'|'l'|'l'|'e'|'h'|#
```

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpfull, I didn't know about the Data.IORef. May I ask you how you implemented the Show instance? When I try to execute statefulExample here it says that there's no instance for (Show (State (Stack Char) ())). The concept of State is new for me.

Comment: I didn't implement a `Show` instance. It's not possibly to show a stateful action, like it's not possible to show any function, really – you should only show _results_ for given input, like in my example. In fact (cf also my comment about your `Show` instance) it it seldom a good idea to implement `Show` instances at all – just use `deriving Show`, if that succeeds you know you have a good `Show` instance, if not then you probably _should not try_.

Comment: Note the call to `execState`.